# what are my chances to call CICS Transactions or COBOL programs from Python

Tags: python, cobol, cics

we have some COBOL Caller Handlers which are executed/called by external applications built in VB/Java. what we are looking is instead of going through other applications, is there way to call those caller handlers directly from Python so we can test them directly from Python automation framework

Answer (score 1):

I have a CICS program/transaction bound to a web interface in CICS, so that i can drive my transaction via http post/put/get, maybe you are looking for a tighter bind though?

Answer (score 0):

CICS supports [SOAP](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=applications-developing-web-services) and [REST](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=applications-developing-http), since 2008 I think.  COBOL natively parses [XML](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=services-processing-xml-input) (and has for over a decade) and [JSON](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=services-processing-json-input) (this is relatively new).

Answer (score 0):

For the Java APIs I would recommend, ditching python and wrting the tests in Groovy.
This is a scripting language that runs on a JVM, which means it can call all java APIs natively.

As well as support the normal builtin scripting stuff like dictionarys, currying functions, regex support -- all valid java code is also valid Groovy code. So you can cut and paste your java API calls into your testing scripts.

Comment: this is what we are thinking...we keep these caller handlers in Stored Procedures and call them from Python using ibm_db package. Its same as calling VB SP's from MYSQL using pyodbc driver

Answer (score 0):

Python is available for z/OS in two distributions: from Rocket Software and (in beta form at the moment) from IBM. They're both free of charge. Here are the relevant links:

https://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source

https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/2020/04/29/python-z-os-beta-is-ready/

Either one should give you the flexibility you need to invoke whatever other z/OS-hosted program you wish to invoke, whatever its programming language, without requiring any sort of network interface or other such configuration. Then you just decide how you'd like to interact with that program. As Cschneid suggested, do you want that to be via REST/JSON APIs? Great, CICS Transaction Server for z/OS supports that. So does Db2 for z/OS ("Db2 Native REST"), which addresses the COBOL part of your question if you're trying to invoke a Db2 stored procedure that happens to be written in COBOL. So does Python.

Another way to figure out a possible path is to figure out how the Visual Basic and Java applications are invoking these COBOL programs. That may not necessarily be the best way, but if it's still a reasonable way then perhaps you could adopt the same basic approach from Python.